# Switching multiple objects to sculpt mode easily

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting

Is there any way to quickly move all my selected objects into sculpt mode? The reason being, I'd like to navigate between them by Alt-clicking them while sculpting. If I select multiple objects, then go to the sculpting tab on the top, it only changes one of the objects into sculpt mode. The only way I found to work around this is one by one selecting the objects and changing them from object mode to sculpt mode. Then if I want to let's say go back to the modeling tab and do some modifications in Edit or Object mode, the objects remain in sculpt mode, so I have to change them back again one by one. Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Select all of the objects you want to move into sculpt mode, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join them into a single object. With this "multi-object" selected, sculpt it as you normally would. After you are done, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go into Edit Mode. Press <kbd>P</kbd> and select "by loose parts" to split them into individual objects again.